# Check if the following ring homomorphism is flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $k$ be a field.

Consider the ring morphism $f: k[x,y,x^{-1}, y^{-1}] \to k[t,t^{-1}]$ where $x \to t$ and $y \to t$. How do we know if $f$ is flat or not?

Now let $R=k[x,y,x^{-1}, y^{-1}]$. Then $k[t,t^{-1}] = R/(x-y)$.

Now consider the exact sequence

$$(x-y) \to R \to R/(x-y).$$

Tensoring this exact sequence with $R/(x-y)$ we get

$$(x-y)/(x-y)^2  \to R/(x-y) \to R/(x-y).$$

But since $(x-y)/(x-y)^2$ is not $0$ the above sequence is not exact.

So, we conclude this morphism is not flat.

Is the above argument ok? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Flat implies torsion free, and obviously this is not the case for R/(x-y).

Comment: You can also show that if R/I is R-flat then $I=I^2$. For this consider the exact sequence $0\to I\to R$ and tensor it with $R/I$ (as you did in your example).